# Laravel 5: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, mysql, validation, constraints, laravel-5

I have a form with the following fields: name, fullname, description, email, password, state, city (filled through Ajax when the state is chosen) and photo (a image upload).
Here's my schema:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('states', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('acronym');
        $table->string('name');
    });

    Schema::create('cities', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('state_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('state_id')->references('id')->on('states');
    });

    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('fullname');
        $table->string('photo');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->integer('city_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
        $table->rememberToken();
    });
}
```

My problem is that when I press the submit button, the following error message appears:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`yearbook`.`users`, CONSTRAINT `users_city_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) REFERENCES `cities` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `description`, `email`) values (Gabriel, Description, email@gmail.com))

So the problem is related to the city_id being a foreign key (the 'value' attribute from the option at the form is the id). Fro exemple:

```
<option value="281">Abaíra</option>
```

But when I try to insert through phpmyadmin, it inserts with no errors.

**So what could be the problem?**

Here's my save method at the controller:

```
public function saveRegister()
{
    $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'fullname' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
        'state' => 'required',
        'city' => 'required',
        'photo' => 'required',
        'photo' => 'image|max:3000000',
    );
    $val = \Validator::make(\Input::all(), $rules);

    if($validar->fails()){
        return redirect('register')->withErrors($val);
    } else {
        $user = new User(array(
            'name' => \Input::get('name'),
            'description' => \Input::get('description'),
            'fullname' => \Input::get('fullname'),
            'email' => \Input::get('email'),
            'city_id' => \Input::get('city'),
        ));
        $user->timestamps = false;
        $user->save();
        return redirect('register')->with('message', 'User saved!');

    }
}
```

Edit: fixed city_id at saveRegister() method.

Comment: You have `city_id` in `users` table but in your code, you've use `city` instead.

Comment: You are right, but I fixed and I still get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of

```
$user = new User(array(
        'name' => \Input::get('name'),
        'description' => \Input::get('description'),
        'fullname' => \Input::get('fullname'),
        'email' => \Input::get('email'),
        'city' => \Input::get('city'),
    ));
```

do this

```
$user = new User();
$user->fill(array(
        'name' => \Input::get('name'),
        'description' => \Input::get('description'),
        'email' => \Input::get('email')
    ));
$user->fullname = \Input::get('fullname');
$user->city= \Input::get('city');
```

or change the `$fillable` property in the model

Comment: Thank you. The problem was the $fillable property: it didn't have the city_id.

Comment: That the common problem, missing the value in fillable. In my case I use '*' on the fillable array but with fk I have had to put '*', 'fk_id'

Answer (score 1):

It may be because your cities.id field is not unsigned whereas your FK fields are unsigned. All columns used in relations must match exactly.

Try changing your code to this:

```
Schema::create('cities', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
```

Comment: try it like this then:

Comment: `$table->unsignedInteger('id', true);`

Comment: Just to clarify, you will need to drop your existing tables and re-run your migrations for this change to take effect.

Comment: I know. I dropped the entire database and did it again, but I got the same result.

Comment: I'll try unsignedInteger.

Comment: does the error occur on migration? or when attempting to run your save method.

Comment: one other thing i'm seeing in my migrations is i'm explicitly setting the engine type to innodb like so:

```
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->unsignedInteger('id', true);
```

Comment: if this error occurs when running the save method, it appears that city_id is not being passed to the insert, as shown in the error sql: `(SQL: insert into users (name, description, email) values (Gabriel, Description, email@gmail.com)` <-- where's city_id? if it's not passed, that would definitely generate a relations error.

Comment: Hi Ian and Pawel you were right the problem was my $fillable variable: it did not have the city_id, so when it tried to save it showed the error. Sorry for your time. Thank you very much.